# Random Weighted Subgraphs

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am working with cross-linguistic semantic maps, such as the one seen [here](http://stedt.berkeley.edu/~stedt-cgi/rootcanal.pl/chap/1.3) for *mouth*.

I want to be able to take a graph of this and extract *n* weighted random subgraphs, where the weights are determined by link weights.  That is, nodes connected by higher weights will be preferentially selected for a random subgraph.  I have googled in vain, mostly getting software and papers on creating fully random graphs with particular subgraph properties.

Staring at the documentation for `networkx` hasn't yielded anything that strikes me as a likely help, but unfortunately I'm a dabbler in this field and may be missing something through terminological ignorance.

I'm looking for suggestions on the correct terminology to find this (if I'm missing something obvious), or pointers to a tool (even for another programming language) that can do this task.

Comment: What do you mean by a subgraph? You want to delete random low-weight edges from your graph? Or you want to delete vertices that are only connected by low-weight edges? How many edges do you want to delete?

Comment: It's likely that you haven't found much because this could be a very expensive operation, depending on what you're asking. An `n`-vertex graph has exponentially many subgraphs.

Comment: I don't want to delete edges, I want to partition the graph into *n* parts randomly, with high-weight edges more likely to end up in the same subgraph.

Comment: What do you mean by "partition the graph"? Do you mean "create disjoint subsets of vertices" or "create disjoint subsets of edges"? Do you want every subset to have the same number of edges/vertices? It's not clear to me how I would look at a graph and say "yes, here are 5 pieces I will cut this in to." What are the criteria?

Comment: I mean disjoint subsets of vertices.  With edges between members of that disjoint subset intact, but no edge outside those.

Comment: Okay. And for an `m`-vertex graph partitioned over `n` vertices, you want `m/n` vertices per graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch of an algorithm.

1. Convert your graph into a distance matrix.
2. Select a cell (`v_0`) at random, using the vanilla Python `random` function.
3. Assuming the graph is undirected, grab either the column or the row containing `v_0` (it's symmetric, so they're the same).
4. Use a [weighted choice function](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/09/weighted-random-choice.html) to grab a vertex that's likely to be far from your initial vertex out of that row. Since your weight is the distance between vertices, that just means feeding the row into `weighted_pick` from the linked snippet, with `picks = 1`. Let this vertex be `v_1`.
5. Zero the row containing `v_0` so that it never gets picked again.
6. Repeat `m/n` times, starting the next iteration with `v_1` as your new starting vertex. Save the vertices you just selected in a subgraph.
7. Repeat the whole process `n` times to get the full list of subgraphs.

This isn't quite what you asked for -- since it selects for long paths rather than heavy edges -- but that's easy to fix. You could tweak your distance matrix such that `d(v_1, v_2) = 0` if there isn't any edge between `v_1` and `v_2`. Then you'll only get connected subgraphs, which appears to be what you want.

This should run in `O(|V|) * t` time, where `t` is the time complexity of your weighted choice function. Unfortunately, `numpy` doesn't say what the time complexity of `searchsorted` is, but I'd guess it's going to be `O(log n)`, since it's doing an insertion into a sorted list. That would give you `O(|V| log |V|)` time for the whole thing, which is pretty good. I'd guess that you could get it done in ~100 lines of Python, if your data was in a nice format to start with.

Comment: See, just knowing about distance matrices makes this all easier to think about.  Thanks!